# how to define table name and conduct multiple table selection

Tags: sql

I need to use multiple table selections in a query in SQL. But how to reference a table selected within a query?

for example: (pseudo code)

```
create table C as
select distinct id, product_code
from (
   select distinct id, product_code 
   from A where dt = '2019-06-01'
) 
inner join B on (select distinct id, product_code 
                 from A where dt='2019-06-01').id = B.id;
```

the code above might be wrong, but the point is that the table A could not be used directly since it's too large and it has to be specified that dt is some specific value. (so I need to select something from A for double times above). And I need to inner join the smaller A' with some other table B.

Is it possible, say, "define" that table A_ = select distinct blabla...from A ... and then join A_ with B within a query?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want a table alias:

```
select distinct id, product_code
from (select distinct id, product_code
      from table_A
      where dt = '2019-06-01'
     ) a inner join
     table_B b
     on a.id = B.id;
```

Comment: so the "a" there defines a name for the table selected and from then on, "a" could be refered below?

Comment: @Benjamin . . . I modified the query to clarify the distinction.  Once `a` is defined, you can use it to reference columns.  However, you cannot use `a` in the `from` clause to refer to the derived table.